# Faster execution of non nulls for a column

Tags: sql-server

I need to get percentage of nulls for a given column in a table. The table contains close to `368081344` records as of now in table. Number of records will increase by 20 million each day. Below is the query am using.

```
SELECT (COUNT_BIG(column)/ count_big(*)) * 100 
from <table>
```

Then, I perform 100 - `above output` to fetch the required output

Please let me know best possible solution which can yield faster result

Comment: This looks alright to me. Are you facing any specific issues with this query?

Comment: Yeah above query is taking 12 mins to respond which is too much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below method :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Id INT
)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       SeqNo = 1,
       NULL "Val"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       SeqNo = SeqNo+1,
       Val
       FROM CTE
          WHERE SeqNo<100
)
INSERT INTO @T(Id)
SELECT Val FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT SeqNo FROM CTE

SELECT
    TotCount = COUNT(1),
    ValCount = SUM(CASE WHEN Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
    NullCount = SUM(CASE WHEN Id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
    NullPercent = (CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN Id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT))*100
    FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer only. Not sure how to get the count for a specific column**

You can speed up the total row count using this query.

```
SELECT      P.ROWS
FROM        SYS.OBJECTS AS O INNER JOIN SYS.PARTITIONS AS P 
            ON O.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE       O.NAME = 'PARENT' AND
            P.INDEX_ID < 2
ORDER BY    O.NAME
```